# Outlook 2016 and several email accounts causing random long hang ups

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-office-2016

We have this secretary that has several heavily used email accounts from contractors in this company added to her Outlook. She uses them to search for emails. However, after trying to repair office that also did not fix it. And since only Outlook is hanging I am led to believe that all these email accounts are the issue.

Is there a trick to optimize all these Office365 accounts in a single instance of outlook or can Outlook just not handle all these emails?

EDIT:

These are active accounts and we use Microsoft Office 365 Exchange.

Offtopic Question:
*Is there maybe another way to better search several email accounts other then using Outlook? Web browsers are out of the question as there are so many account you would have to sign in and out of.*

Comment: So are these emails accounts active and she has access to them or archived data? Are you storing .ost file locally (cached mode) or working directly off the server? I'm not sure if you're trying to access these via a desktop application like office 2016 or office 2013? Of if you're using online, web based office 365? or both? If using exchange, do you manage it yourself or vendor?

Comment: These are active accounts. They are your typical locally saved .ost files

Comment: Does everything load and respond well via OWA?